# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre estos dos casos de anteposiciones del adjetivo?

Tags: gramática, lingüística

I am studying advanced spanish grammar and got stuck on the concept of "anteposiciones del adjetivo", could some generous soul explain me the difference between these two cases of the phenomenon as described in my book ?

« En ocasiones lloraba en la penumbra de **una gris tarde** de domingo »

« A **claras luces** eran mentiras las que nos contaba Diego »

Answer (score 3):

When an *adjetivo* goes before the noun it usually has an explicative (*explicativo* or *epíteto*) function. You are describing the noun.

When it goes after the noun, it usally has a specification (*especificativo*) function. You are specifying which one.

For instance, if you say:

> Golpeó la blanca pelota.

It means he hit the ball (probably there wasn't more than one), and you are explaining that the ball was white.

> Golpeó la pelota blanca.
> Probably there is more than one ball, and it's the white one that he hit.

The *anteposiciones* are not used very often on spoken language, and they're usually used as an embelishment of language, like in poetry or poetic prose.